# Connecting to a VPN behind a NETGEAR WNDR3400v2

Tags: vpn, firewall

At my wits end here. I have a ZyXel VPN Firewall, which I can "VPN into" from the outside as long as it's connected directly to my cable modem. However I need the ZyXel WAN port connected to the LAN port on my internet connected NetGear WNDR3400v2.

I have the ZyXel's internal WAN IP set as the default DMZ server in my NetGear and I can hit all of the configured services on the ZyXel (such as RDP) from outside - but I can't get the VPN to connect.

It's like the NetGear just doesn't respect the DMZ rule for the VPN packets or something.

I need my VPN client (#1 on the diagram) to connect to the VPN Server (#5 on the diagram).

Are there any special instructions when using the NETGEAR WNDR3400v2?

**VPN Client Log:**

```
20181001 23:01:45:221 Default (SA VPT_Gateway-VPT_Tunnel-P2) is opening.
20181001 23:01:45:221 Default (SA VPT_Gateway-P1) SEND phase 1 Main Mode  [SA] [VID] [VID] [VID] [VID] [VID]
20181001 23:01:45:221 Default (SA VPT_Gateway-P1) RECV phase 1 Main Mode  [SA] [VID] [VID] [VID] [VID] [VID] [VID] [VID] [VID] [VID]
20181001 23:01:45:236 Default (SA VPT_Gateway-P1) SEND phase 1 Main Mode  [KEY_EXCH] [NONCE] [NAT_D] [NAT_D]
20181001 23:01:45:330 Default (SA VPT_Gateway-P1) RECV phase 1 Main Mode  [KEY_EXCH] [NONCE] [NAT_D] [NAT_D]
20181001 23:01:45:330 Default (SA VPT_Gateway-P1) SEND phase 1 Main Mode  [HASH] [ID]
20181001 23:01:45:330 Default message_parse_payloads: reserved field non-zero: 96
20181001 23:01:45:330 Default dropped message from 75.190.189.35 due to notification type PAYLOAD_MALFORMED
20181001 23:01:45:330 Default (SA <unknown>) SEND Informational  [NOTIFY] with PAYLOAD_MALFORMED error
20181001 23:01:45:330 Default (SA VPT_Gateway-P1) RECV Informational  [NOTIFY] with PAYLOAD_MALFORMED error
20181001 23:01:45:330 Default Received INFORMATIONAL message. Aborting connection
20181001 23:02:15:930 Default (SA <unknown>) SEND Informational  [HASH] [NOTIFY] type DPD_R_U_THERE
20181001 23:02:15:930 Default ipsec_get_keystate: no keystate in ISAKMP SA 01CFCF40 (possibly AUTH_FAILED from gateway)
```

**Terribly Laughable Diagram**

[image: Terrible Diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specified router WNDR3400v2 doesn't support GRE-47 and also does not have explicit support for VPN Pass-through. Upgraded #3 on the diagram to a NetGear AC1600 and everything is working fine.